# Get node tree result values at certain points on mesh surface using Python?

Tags: python, node-editor, shaders, displacement

Blender 2.80. I have material with several different textures (generated noises, images, etc.) mixed using nodes in Shader Editor. This material is assigned to the mesh. Is it possible using Python somehow to get resulting values of node tree (such as value, RGB, etc.) at exact points on the surface of the mesh (e.g. at each vertex location) without baking node tree to Image?

Comment: This isn't possible, because the shader need to be compiled and the resulting rendered value depends on the view angle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As I see it, compiling is going on inside shaders programs - which truly depends on the view angle - while the texture information that is used for it is kind of constant and depends only on texture's settings and texture coordinates. Is it wrong? I don't need shaders BSDF visual representation information - just an access to texture information before shaders which is used for compiling, at certain coordinates.

Comment: Yes that is certainly possible given the UV map, texture and a point on the surface.